# How does NPM handle Conflicts with Sub/Transitive Dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

I've [just discovered](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/) (for myself) that NPM doesn't work like other package management systems I've used in the past.  My basic understanding of things is that each of my dependencies will also have its own `node_modules` folder with it's own dependencies (and, with more recent versions of npm, that this second `node_modules` folder will only be created when there's a version conflict)

This seems pretty neat, but I'm left wondering how npm handles -- sub-sub? -- dependency conflicts.   I apologies for not having a better grip on the language -- but here's what I mean.

I want to install version 3.0 of `@foo/bar` into my project.

A second-package -- let's call it `@second/package` -- I have wants to install version 2.0 of `@foo/bar`.

I now understand how this is possible with NPM.  The `@second/package` will have it's own `node_modules` folder with version 2.0 of `@foo/bar`

```
./node_modules/@foo/bar                              # version 3.0
./node_modules/@second/package/node_modules/@foo/bar # version 2.0
```

However --

I also want to install version 8.0 of `@zip/zap`.

But `@second/package` wants install version 7.0 of `@zip/zap`.

**And version 2.0 of `@foo/bar` wants to install version 6.0 of `@zip/zap`.**

```
./node_modules/@foo/bar                              # version 3.0
./node_modules/@zip/zap                              # version 8.0
./node_modules/@second/package/node_modules/@foo/bar # version 2.0
./node_modules/@second/package/node_modules/@zip/zip # version 7.0    

# where does version 6.0 of @zip/zap go?
```

Where does version 6.0 of `@zip/zap` end up?  Does npm create a *third* level `node_module` folder, or does it give up and say it can't resolve this dependency tree?  Or some third thing?  Or is my understanding of npm still flawed?

Before I go and figure out how to setup my own npm repository with fake packages to test this out, I thought it'd be better to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM, to my surprise, just *does the right thing* and continues to nest sub-dependency dependencies.  i.e., the answer the question

> where does version 6.0 of @zip/zap go?

is

```
./node_modules/@second/package/node_modules/@foo/bar/node_modules/@zip/zap
```